# Qt connect signal to slot

Tags: qt, connect, slot

I have a main window class which contains a QSplitter widget (among other widgets). The contents of this splitter are populated by the widgets that are in another class.

Inside this other Widgwt I have a layout with a QPushButton called test_btn added I also have a function defined in the header file under `public slots:` called test_function which has the corresponding code in the cpp file:

```
cout << "Test!" << endl;
```

I try and call this function using the following code:

```
connect(test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(test_function()));
```

The widgets and buttons appear as expected in the application but when I click it nothing happens.

If I add the same `connect` code to the main window it works (for calling a test function from the main window) i.e.

```
connect(cc_point.test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(main_win_test_function()));
```

I cant call the test function from the other class unless I call it from the `main_win_test_function()`

I know I'm missing the 'receiver widget' from the connect statement, although it does work without it in the main window class and I don't get any errors when compiling.

Do I need to define the parent or something in the `other_class`?

main_window.cpp:

```
main_window::main_window()
{
    add_splitter();

    QGridLayout *window_layout = new QGridLayout;

    window_layout->setSpacing(0);
    window_layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    window_layout->addWidget(splitter1, 0, 0);

    set_layout(window_layout);
}

void main_window::add_splitter()
{
     other_class oc_point;

     splitter1 = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal);

     splitter1->addWidget(oc_point.oc_widget);
}
```

other_class.cpp:

```
other_class:other_class()
{
     oc_widget = new QWidget;

     QGridLayout *other_layout = new QGridLayout(oc_widget);

     test_btn = new QPushButton;
     test_btn->setText("Test Button");

     connect(test_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), test_btn->parent(), SLOT(test_function());
     other_layout->addWidget(test_btn);
}

void other_class::test_function()
{
     cout << "Test output" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

QApplication app(argc, argv);

main_window window;

window.resize(1100, 700);
window.setWindowTitle("Qt Test");
window.setWindowIcon(QIcon (":/images/icon_1.png"));
window.setMinimumHeight(500);
window.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

As I mentioned above, this all works fine as far as the window getting created and the widgets being displayed goes, but the test_function doesn't get called when I click the button. Let me know if I need to include my header files as well.

Comment: Now you understand why posting code is *very important*. The bug was obvious the second I looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

In `main_window::add_splitter()`, the `oc_point` is destroyed as soon as the function returns. It's not the connection that is the problem, the problem is that your object vanishes before you can do anything useful with it.

Below is a self-contained example that demonstrates this problem in both Qt 4 and 5. As soon as you click "Delete Other", the Test Button doesn't work.

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>

class Other : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget *m_widget;
    Q_SLOT void testFunction() {
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Test", "Slot works.");
    }
public:
    QWidget *widget() const { return m_widget; }
    Other(QObject *parent = 0) : m_widget(new QWidget), QObject(parent) {
        QGridLayout *l = new QGridLayout(m_widget);
        QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Test Button");
        l->addWidget(btn);
        connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testFunction()));
    }
    ~Other() { if (!m_widget->parent()) delete m_widget; }
};

class Main : public QWidget
{
public:
    Main(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0) : QWidget(parent, f) {
        QGridLayout *l = new QGridLayout(this);
        QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Delete Other");
        Other *o = new Other(this);
        QSplitter *spl = new QSplitter;
        spl->addWidget(o->widget());
        l->addWidget(spl);
        l->addWidget(btn);
        connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), o, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Main w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried this as well and it didn't work either, is it possible that because I have a `Qwidget` with a `layout` in the main class that has a `Qsplitter` which then has a 'oc_point.QWidget` which in turn has a `layout` with `test_btn` added that the parent of the `test_btn` doesn't have the test_function() slot? (This is possibly confusing to follow, so let me know if it would be easier for me to add my actual code)

Comment: You **absolutely, positively need to show your code**. Make a self-contained, single-file example. No `.h` files, nothing like that. Just one `main.cpp` file, and one `.pro` file. Add `#include "main.moc"` at the end so that you don't need a separate header file. Re-run quake, rebuild, and post here once you've verified that it works and demonstrates the problem. Otherwise it's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: How do I add the `other_widget` to the `splitter1` without the object being destroyed? Do I have to return the object, or widget ID or something, or is there a better way of doing this without the `oc_point` because obviously trying to add it using `other_class.other_widget` gives me the 'expected primary expression before '.' error'

Comment: All QWidgets are QObjects. Just create the new object on the heap instead of on the stack, and make it owned by something that lives as long as necessary. That's all. Your issue in the code you present is that `oc_point` is on the stack, not on the heap. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

After your objects are initialized, you should connected them to each other.  Explicitly naming whose slots are whose and whose signals are whose, will help a lot.

Sometimes I'll make a helper function `void Widget::connectTo__Class__(Class * class_ptr);`

Then in that function call I'll connect the slots that cross the class/parent/inheritance boundaries.

Here is an example implementation:

```
void Widget::connectTo__Class__(Class * class_ptr)
{
    QObject::connect(this,      SIGNAL(myWidgetSignal()), 
                     class_ptr, SLOT(myClassSlot()));

    QObject::connect(class_ptr, SIGNAL(myClassSignal()), 
                     this,      SLOT(myWidgetSlot()));
}
```

Also keep in mind that the runtime will complain when you are doing something wrong, such as if the `class_ptr` is `null`, or if `myClassSignal` doesn't exist.  You can see these errors in the application output when you run it in Debug mode.

And give `QDebug` a try sometime.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/debug.html

EDIT:
To fix any header class recursive definition problems, do the following:

In your header file for one of the classes only prototype the class, don't include it:

in widget.h:

```
// #include "myclass.cpp" // Should be commented out!

class MyClass; // This prototype avoids the recursion

// ...

class Widget
{
    // ...

    public:
        void connectToMyClass(Class * class_ptr);

    // ...
}
```

Then in the cpp file, you do the include.

```
#include "myclass.h"

void Widget::connectToMyClass(Class * class_ptr)
{
    // ...
}
```

Another way around this issue is to use `QObject *` instead of `Class *`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response to this. I tried what you suggested with the code, although I'm not sure I'm implementing it correctly, I can't add these to the `other_class` cpp file because it doesn't build properly with recursive pointers and adding it to the main_window class doesn't seem to work either, although I am probably not doing it correctly.

Comment: To fix that issue, don't include the other class in both places.